# Algebra-valued field

Tags: field-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills

What is an algebra-valued field in QFT?
For instance the stress-field tensor times its corresponding generator gives the algebra-valued field
$$F_{\mu,\nu} = (g_i)(F_i)_{\mu,\nu}$$
But what does this mean? Or why is it important enough so as to give it a name?

Comment: I'm not sure why you call this a "name" - it's just a factual description. Field strength tensors are functions that have a Lie algebra as their space of values (i.e. they are "Lie algebra-valued"), just like ordinary vector fields are functions that have vectors as their space of values (they are "vector-valued"). What's the question about that?

Answer (score 0):

An algebra-valued field is simply a field that takes value in an algebra. Usually, it is useful in Yang-Mills theory but can have applications in TQFT like for the Chern-Simons theories. It is a very important feature of quantum field theories since the field inherits the commutations relations of the algebra it is defined on. For example, take a field represented by a $\mathfrak{su}(3)$-valued 1 form $A=A^i \tau^i dx^\mu$. Then you can define an exterior gauge covariant derivative $d_AV=dV+[V,A]_{\mathfrak{su}(3)}$, where the commutator contains tensor products. The curvature 2-form is then given by:
\begin{align*}
F&=F^i \tau ^i dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu=d_A A=dA+[A,A]_{\mathfrak{su}(3)}
\\
&=(\partial_\mu A^i_\nu-\partial_\nu A^i_\mu+f^{ijk}A^j_\mu A^k_\nu)\tau^i dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu.
\end{align*}
Then the components of the $\mathfrak{su}(3)$-valued curvature field are $\partial_\mu A^i_\nu-\partial_\nu A^i_\mu+f^{ijk}A^j_\mu A^k_\nu$. We see in the structure constants $f^{ijk}$ that there's a non-abelian term arising from our consideration of algebra-valued field. Indeed, without the gauge covariant derivative we find just a term like $\partial_\mu A_\nu -\partial_\nu A_\mu$, which is the wrong object to describe a theory of algebra-valued fields.

In quantum field theory in curved space-time, when it comes to defining spin 1/2 particles in a gravitational field, one has to define tetrads as $\text{Cliff}_{1,3}^\mathbb{C}$-valued one-forms and spin connections as $\mathfrak{spin}(1,3)$-valued one-forms. Then thee Riemann curvature is given by $d_\omega \omega$ (modulo the action of the tetrads). Here we see again that the gauge covariant exterior derivative $d_\omega$ is important because if we forget about the $\mathfrak{spin}(1,3)$ structure of the form, then we arrive at a wrong expression!

Answer (score 0):

A field is generally the section of a bundle over spacetime. When the field itself said to be valued in an algebra, this is because the bundle has fibres which are algebras.

A bundle should be thought of as a bundle of fibres. Fibres run vertically, whereas section is short for cross section and here we are cutting across. Hemce a cross section will have a value in each fibre, and as each fibre is an algebra, it is algebra valued.

The connection field is a Lie algebra valued field. Since connections are important in physics for representing gauge fields and hence gauge bosons such as the photon or the gluons, algebra valued fields are important in physics